# ag-grid Upgrading from community to enterprise with angular

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, ag-grid

I have angular @angular/cli                      8.3.19

My project builds fine with the community version, but when I make the following change

```
import {AllCommunityModules} from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';
to
import {AllCommunityModules} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
```

the build process fails

```
ng build --verbose

<w> [webpack.Progress] 37511ms building
<i> [webpack.Progress] 77ms finish module graph
<i> [webpack.Progress] 135ms chunk graph
<i> [webpack.Progress] 69ms module optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 56ms advanced chunk optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 36ms before module ids
<i> [webpack.Progress] 52ms module id optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 28ms after chunk id optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 253ms hashing
<i> [webpack.Progress] 370ms chunk assets processing
<i> [webpack.Progress] 19ms additional chunk assets processing
<w> [webpack.Progress] 7450ms after chunk asset optimization
<w> [webpack.Progress] 1789ms emitting
**Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...**
An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
See "/private/var/folders/1s/pwh7yh656jsbttp9c0383jnc0000gn/T/ng-8LZHsO/angular-errors.log" for further details.

error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (work/dm/test-platform/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker.onExit (work/dm/test-platform/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:263:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
```

The build spins its wheels for a minute or two before throwing the exception

When importing from the community version the generating diffs step is fast

I've tried AllModules instead of AllCommunityModules and the same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the tsconfig.app.json target from es2015 back down to es5 and try?, this may disable differential loading